# How do I make available *.mem and *.data files that sit alongside javascript files that need them, in vendor/assets/javascripts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

In a rails project, can javascript files that sit in `vendor/assets/javascript` access non-js files such as `*.data` and `*.mem` files that sit next to them?

I've tried adding them to `config.assets.precompile` like so:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['javascripts/foo.mem']
config.assets.precompile += ['javascripts/bar.data']
```

Am  I referencing them incorrectly, or is this even possible?  Is precompiling excluding them?  What would be a way around this?  Would I need to use a js library package manager, create a lib through that, install with `npm`, and require that in `application.js`, or can I get away with something simpler?

Comment: Can you please tell us what is the purpose of these (*.data and *.mem) files? I mean how you are going to use this files?

Comment: I actually cannot tell you that, as it is a 3rd party lib, and so it is being placed in `vendor/assets/javascripts` directory instead of `assets/javascript` directory.  I see that the lib is functional with: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`.  I'm wondering if it isn't working in rails because those files are not included alongside the javascript files that use them, or for some other reason.

Comment: Turns out one way is to stash them in the `public` directory, though, away from the js files.  Moving the js files next to them didn't work; having another issue now, though, which after digging deeper, I believe warrants a separate question.